# How can I fill an html table-cell with a background-color in html for difference browsers

Tags: html, css

I have the following piece of HTML that creates a table with a scrollbar at the last column. My problem is that IE renders it differently than Firefox. Any clue would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>Test of tables and CSS</title>
<style type="text/css">
td
{
   border:solid 1px #000000;
   padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="0" style="border:solid 1px #000000;border-collapse:separate;padding:0 0         0 0;">
<tr>
<td>Col 1 1</td>
<td>Col 1 2</td>
<td rowspan="5" style="width: 1px; padding: 0 0 0 0;height:100%;"><table cellspacing="0" style="border: none; height:100%;border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0 0 0  0;">
<tr><td style="border: none; height: 1px; background-color: #C9D8FC;"><img alt="" src="../img/ico/ScrollUp.gif" style="border: none;" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td style="border: none; height: auto; background-color: #C9D8FC;"></td></tr>
<tr><td style="border: none; height: 1px; vertical-align: bottom; background-color:#C9D8FC;"><img alt="" src="../img/ico/ScrollDown.gif" style="border:none;" /></td></tr>
</table></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Col 2 1</td>
<td>Col 2 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Col 3 1</td>
<td>Col 3 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Col 4 1</td>
<td>Col 4 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Col 5 1</td>
<td>Col 5 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Firefox:
[image]

IE 8:
[image]

Comment: Heavily styling HTML tables is a recipe for pain.  Is it possible for you to instead wrap a DIV around the table and assign an explicit height and text-overflow:auto or text-overflow: scroll to that DIV?

Comment: the code you paste above give me the same result in firefox and ie

Comment: @Ben: any suggestion on how to do that? @Sotiris, not for Firefox 3.6 and IE 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use conditional comments in your header to send specific style declarations to internet explorer?

```
<!--[if IE]>
Only IE will output what's between these brackets, style declarations etc.
<![endif]-->
```

[Read More](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Comment: sorry buddy, just clarified my answer

Answer (score 0):

height: auto; this is not working correctly in IE,

try adding     display: block

Answer (score 0):

Is this the problem?

```
vstyle="... should be style="...
```

also you might want to add a class to your tables instead of putting the styles inline, it makes it easier to read but won't make a difference in the rendering

Comment: Thank you, but I cann't find vstyle in my code.. I am using css in general, but I didn't use it here to try to isolate the problem :)

Comment: ok, that's why I couldn't find it. It's a copy-paste mistake.. Sorry for that.. still not working..